# PHP mysqli query result showing twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i'm doing a query and fetching the results with fetch_assoc(), the problem comes inside, inside I do another query with the result of the first query, then i do an If statement to check if there are results, it should enter the if ONCE, but for some reason it enters twice and i can't figure it out. Here is the code.

```
$query = "SELECT IDS,fecha_finalizacion,hora_finalizacion FROM subastas WHERE IDS NOT IN (SELECT IDS FROM subastas_finalizadas) AND Finalizada='S'";

if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $pujaNC = $db->query("Select IDS,ID_puja,fecha_noconfirm,hora_noconfirm FROM pujas_noconfirm WHERE IDS=" . $row['IDS'] ." ORDER BY monto asc limit 1");
    while ($rowPNC = $pujaNC->fetch_assoc()) {
        $infoPNC=$rowPNC;
    }
    if($infoPNC){
        echo "BIDNC: ".$infoPNC['IDS']." ".$infoPNC['ID_puja']." <br/>";
    }
   }

}
```

It should show BIDNC: 35 107 and then BIDNC empty.

Comment: So yeah I think I fugured it out just after I asked the question jaja, i was asking if($vairbale) and the varibale is of course full from the first loop of the while, i used ->num_rows and it works fine I think

Comment: You have your info variable in the first while loop. Move it out and it will only echo once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think you need to move your if condition

```
if ($result = $db->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pujaNC = $db->query("Select IDS,ID_puja,fecha_noconfirm,hora_noconfirm FROM pujas_noconfirm WHERE IDS=" . $row['IDS'] ." ORDER BY monto asc limit 1");
        while ($rowPNC = $pujaNC->fetch_assoc()) {
            $infoPNC=$rowPNC;
        }
    }
    if($infoPNC){
        echo "BIDNC: ".$infoPNC['IDS']." ".$infoPNC['ID_puja']." <br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that too, but I used ->num_rows intead and it works better